# openni2 load oni file in Indigo

Tags: ros, openni2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not able to load a oni file (OpenNI record file) with openni2 in Indigo. In Hydro I was able to load it simply with:

```
roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch device_id:=/path/to/your/file.oni
```

but in Indigo openni2 still tries to open the real device.
Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220301/openni2-load-oni-file-in-indigo/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2015-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the issue, by changing these lines on openni2_camera (lines 682):

```
 // check if device_id is a oni file
   else if( device_id.size() - device_id.rfind(".oni") == 4 ) {
         return device_id;
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0